# Apple Photos has given the same name to dozens of photos, as if they were different people

Tags: photos

Photos of "Patricia" are now listed as if they were dozens of different "Patricia" -- even though the name for each "person" is exactly the same. How can I combine all of these into a single record?

Comment: Photos on iOS or Photos on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply merge people.

**On iOS:**

1. Go to People folder in Photos app
2. Click on 'Select' (top right corner)
3. Select the people you want to merge
4. Click on 'Merge' (bottom right corner)
5. It shows an alert, you choose 'Merge'

**On Mac:**

1. Go to People tab in Photos app
2. Select the people you want to merge
3. Right mouse click and choose 'Merge'
4. It shows an alert, you choose 'Merge'